# Is GraphQL-SPQR library production-ready?

Tags: graphql-java, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

I'm working on an existing REST API project and trying to migrate it to GraphQL using graphql-spqr library. Can someone please help me with whether this library is production-ready? Has anyone used spqr library in their product?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we used spqr 0.9.9 over an year at production. works fine!